# Bitcoin to Dollar Conversion

Tags: api, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I am making a project to fetch data of cryptocurrencies using an API

```
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD
```

`VOLUME24HOUR":373400.47865766`; How to convert this into $

If I want to get let's say Market CAP

SO THE API return this ,`"MKTCAP":"$ 90.90 B"`, what does `B` mean also they don't match Market Cap according to [this website](https://www.livecoinwatch.com/price/Ethereum-ETH) is `$91,295,043,296`

**Question**

How do I get the correct data ?

Comment: The B in "MKTCAP":"$ 90.90 B" stands for *Billion*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The API endpoint IS returning USD values, unless you specify a different currency. You're passing in USD to the URL in this chunk `tsyms=USD`

According to the API documentation (https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-data-price-), the `tsyms` parameter takes a currency (or crypto currency) shorthand and returns the values in that specified currency.

Comment: The data in the two websites don't match ,See market cap they dont match

Comment: IF u anwer it I will acept ur answer

Comment: Different exchanges / markets will have different caps and values. GDAX will be different from Gemini, will be different from CoinMarket Cap, will be different from Live Coin Watch. This is normal.